# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln(x)$ via $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x \exp(x)$ - is the composition to the right licit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The high-school classes from a well-known high-school teacher of my country justify the limit of $x \ln(x)$ at $0$ by composing (i.e. doing a change of variable $X= \ln(x)$) on the right by the exponential function. The limit of $x \exp(x)$ at $-\infty$ being known, we can conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln(x) = 0$.

I assume the theorem used here is the limit composition theorem. The limit composition theorem says:

> If $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = c$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = b$ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = c$. Here, $a,b,c$ are chosen in the extended real number line and $f,g$ are reals-to-reals functions.

However, in order to use the limit composition theorem, one must *be sure* that $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = c$ exists. So, what the high-school teacher is doing here (composing to the right by $\exp$) is not allowed - since we don't know if $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln(x)$ exists.

Here's a short example to show composing to the right is non-sense if we don't make sure that $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = c$ exists:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} (-1)^x \text{doesn't exist}$$
$$\text{However, } \lim_{x\to +\infty} (-1)^{2x} = 1$$

If we keep using the high-school teacher's method, how to prove $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln(x)$ exists ?

If we don't, how to prove the limit of $x \ln(x)$ at $0$ is $0$ through another way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are choosing $f(x)= x\exp(x)$ and $g(x)=\ln x$ then it is known that $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=0$ so you conclude $$\lim_{x\downarrow0}x\ln(x)=\lim_{x\downarrow0}f(g(x))=0.$$ This derivation holds without proving à priori that $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}x\ln(x)$ exists.

Comment: Also I don't get your counter-example, as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-1)^{2x}$$ also doesn't exist, except if you restrict $x$ to integers (in which case you leave the setting of the Theorem).

Comment: Oh, isn't $(-1)^{2x}$ equal to $1^x$  ?

Comment: Well no, consider $x=\frac 12$, then LHS is $-1$ but RHS is $1$. The identity $$a^{x y}=(a^x)^y$$ is in general only true for $a\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=x\log x $, what you know is that
$$
\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(e^t)=0.
$$
This means that if you fix $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$, there exists $t_0$ such that $f(e^t)<\e$ for all $t<t_0$. As $\lim_{x \to0}\log x=-\infty$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\log x<t_0$ when $x<\delta$. For such $x$, we have $$
f(x)=f(e^{\log x})<\e.
$$
And that's the definition of limit: given $\e>0$ we found $\delta>0$ such that  $|f(x)|<\e$ whenever $0<x<\delta$; that is
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0.
$$

Comment: Can I read your $\log$ as if it were a $\ln$ ? There're some people that use the convention $\log(x)= \frac{\ln(x)}{ln(10)}$

Comment: Yes.  There's no universally agreed convention. In math it is common to use log for the natural logarithm. In Engineering and elementary calculus classes ln is common. And in Computer Science often log is reserved for base 2.